# How to Create load more pagination for my wordpress theme without a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming

I am developing a wordpress theme for the first time. I have done pretty much everything I need to do except the pagination.

I know that by default, wordpress will load 10 pages on homepage. I did my research on how to create load more button for wordpress themes and all I am seeing involves downloading a plugin called "Ajax" from the wordpress store.

But that means there won't be any pagination if the user doesn't download the plugin.

In other words, all I'm saying is that I want to create a theme with a load more pagination baked into it.

Can anyone help me out with this.
Thanks.

Comment: There are quite a few tutorials online about this topic. Googling "wordpress load more posts ajax without plugin" (without quotes) got me over 1,300,000 results. Have you tried any of these tutorials yet?

Comment: Yes I have, but none are working the way I want it to work.

Comment: You'll need to share the code you have tried and explain how do you expect it to work vs what's actually happening in order for us to be able to help. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)